# How to make and insert Banner AdMob Fragments in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, admob, banner-ads

I am a noob in android studio. And I want to put an ad on multiple activities. Some say that it needs an admob fragment to make it possible. So can someone give me an example or source code for the banner admob fragment.

Comment: large Banner ya small means 50 dp height ya  large 240X320 dp banner size

Comment: I recommend you check the following get started guide: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

Answer (score 0):

Add this code and show **InterstitialAd** in your activity in `onCreate`

```
  InterstitialAd interAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
            interAd.setAdUnitId("Add your adMob key");
            requestNewInterstitial();

            interAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    displayInterstitial();
                }
            });


     public void displayInterstitial(){

    if (interAd.isLoaded()){
        interAd.show();

    };
}

private void requestNewInterstitial() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .build();
    interAd.loadAd(adRequest);

}
```

Comment: Interstitials are not banners. And interstitials are never used with fragments as they appear fullscreen and not as part of a screen. You're not really answering the question.

Comment: sorry , ok i am sending banner code..